# Connect-PnPOnline' command was found in the module 'PnP.PowerShell', but the module could not be loaded

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to use Connect-PnPOnline to conenct to a sharepoint site but receiving the following error.

```
Connect-PnPOnline: The 'Connect-PnPOnline' command was found in the module 'PnP.PowerShell', but the module could not be loaded due to the following error: [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant, Version=16.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. Could not find or load a specific file. (0x80131621)]
For more information, run 'Import-Module PnP.PowerShell'.
```

whenever i try to run 'Import-Module PnP.PowerShell' i receive

```
Import-Module: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant, Version=16.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. Could not find or load a specific file. (0x80131621)
```

running Get-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -ListAvailable | Select-Object Name,Version gets me nothing.

it's like i have PnP powershell installed but its not installed? Anyone have any tips on how i can solve this?

Comment: Perhaps [this discussion](https://github.com/pnp/powershell/discussions/58) can help you

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the 'Connect-PnPOnline' command was found in the 'PnP.PowerShell' module, but the module could not be loaded due to a missing assembly file. The missing assembly file is 'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant, Version=16.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. To resolve this issue, try installing the 'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant' assembly file. You can also try running the following command before importing the 'PnP.PowerShell' module:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
```

This command loads the 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client' assembly, which may resolve the missing assembly file error.